# Calling webservice from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Does calling the webservice/API from Oracle Database require internet? If so, how can call the procedure from the Oracle DB without opening the DB server to internet. Please advise.

Comment: Is it an internet web service? Do you have a firewall blocking the reuired port? Talk to your network people. use `Postman` to test

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes internet web service. Network team says its a security issue to open the internet in the DB Server. Is there any workaround  to overcome this?

Comment: You are trying to connect _outwards_ from your database server to the internet right? Just get on the server, open a browser and type in the endpoint. It'll probably work unless your sevrver team specifically blocks outgoing to the internet (this is not normal)

Comment: If on the other hand you want to connect into your database from an internet address, it's completely normal to not allow this. But it sounds like you want to connect outwards from your db srver to a web service

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Endpoint is not accessible. Is it possible to open only the outgoing to the internet.

Comment: What error do you get? Yes it's possible to just open an outgoing port to the internet but I can't convince your network people to do that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am getting "ORA-29273: HTTP request failed" error

Comment: That is not calling the endpoint from  browser. Please try from a browser

Comment: as per this you should also dig deeper and find any other oracle errors http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_29273_http_request_failed.htm

Answer (score 0):

sure ,you need the internet to access the web service ,if it is not in your local area network